# Use a CASE WHEN to populate from a DIFFERENT row's conditions?

Tags: sql, join, case

I am using CASE WHENs in SQL to calculate a new column based on different calculation criteria within each GROUP. The data for each Account flows through a series of GROUPs over time--most of the time it increases, but there ***are*** cases when it can remain the same or even decrease.

Please find the simplified example of my data and calculations below:

```
======================================
|     ------ SAMPLE TABLE ------     |
======================================
| ACCT | MONTH | GROUP | VAL1 | VAL2 | 
--------------------------------------
|   A  |  Jan  |   1   |   2  |   5  |
|   A  |  Feb  |   2   |   4  |   9  |
|   A  |  Mar  |   3   |   5  |  10  |
|   B  |  Jan  |   1   |  10  |  15  |
|   B  |  Feb  |   2   |   6  |   9  |
|   B  |  Mar  |   2   |  10  |   8  |
|   B  |  Apr  |   3   |   8  |  12  |
|   B  |  May  |   3   |   6  |  11  |
--------------------------------------

==============================================
|       ----- SAMPLE CALCULATIONS -----      |
==============================================
| GROUP = 1: VAL1 + VAL2                     |
| GROUP = 2: VAL1 - VAL2                     |
| GROUP = 3: Output of most recent GROUP = 2 |
----------------------------------------------
```

I want to calculate a new column (not shown) for all rows. Note that the calculation criteria for GROUP = 3 is simply "use the latest entry of the previous group's calculated output". While it might be tempting to just use the same calculation formula again from GROUP = 2, the values in the GROUP = 3 row will be different. For Accounts A and B respectively, here are the challenges I am facing:

**Account A**: How do I calculate the value in GROUP = 2 and then populate it for GROUP = 3?

**Account B:** This is more complicated and I do have multiple instances such as this. The first instance of GROUP = 3 will use the same logic as in Account A above. However, for subsequent instances of GROUP = 3, it should either refer back to the latest GROUP = 2 and replicate the calculation or the earliest GROUP = 3 and replicate the value populated using the method in Account A (both methods should still yield the same outcome).

Hope this is clear enough to understand. Thank you in advance and I am happy to answer any clarifying questions!

Comment: any chance of having it in sql-fiddle? what sort of db are we looking at>?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 I believe. What is "sql-fiddle"? Sorry, not familiar.

Comment: you can build your schema here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I see. Does that help users to try their queries? Just want to make sure I get the idea of this site.

Comment: yes so we don't have to build your table and data... with that tool we can test queries

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b43bd Does this work okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stay away from tracking dates using strings like 'Jan', 'Feb', etc. Your question requires ordering the records in time, but if you performed an ordering on your Month field, it would order it as a string (i.e., 'Feb','Jan','Mar'). In addition, you should record the exact date, not just the month, otherwise you cannot guarantee accurate time ordering over multiple years.

That being said, there are a few different ways to do this, and here's one that I think is pretty cool. First of all, you need to join records over ACCT where the left table group is 3 and the right table is the most recent non-group-3 data. This query:

```
select
          a1.ACCT
        , DATEPART(MM, a1.Mnth + ' 1 2017') as Mnth -- see what a pain it is to use strings instead of dates?
        , a1.Grp
        , a1.Val1
        , a1.Val2
        , a2.ACCT
        , DATEPART(MM, a2.Mnth + ' 1 2017') as Mnth
        , a2.Grp
        , a2.Val1
        , a2.Val2
    from #A a1
    outer apply (
        select top 1 *
            from #A
            where ACCT = a1.ACCT -- match on the account
                and Grp < 3
                and a1.Grp = 3 -- I'll explain at the end why we don't actually need this
                and DATEPART(MM, Mnth + ' 1 2017') < DATEPART(MM, a1.Mnth + ' 1 2017') -- grab all previous dates
            order by DATEPART(MM, Mnth + ' 1 2017') desc -- grab the latest previous date (along with the top command)

    ) as a2
    order by  a1.ACCT
            , DATEPART(MM, a1.Mnth + ' 1 2017')
```

produces the following table:

```
+ ---- + ---- + --- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- +
| ACCT | Mnth | Grp | Val1 | Val2 | ACCT | Mnth | Grp  | Val1 | Val2 |
+ ---- + ---- + --- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- +
| A    | 1    | 1   | 2    | 5    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| A    | 2    | 2   | 4    | 9    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 
| A    | 3    | 3   | 5    | 10   | A    | 2    | 2    | 4    | 9    | 
| B    | 1    | 1   | 10   | 15   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 
| B    | 2    | 2   | 6    | 9    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 
| B    | 3    | 2   | 10   | 8    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 
| B    | 4    | 3   | 8    | 12   | B    | 3    | 2    | 10   | 8    | 
| B    | 5    | 3   | 6    | 11   | B    | 4    | 3    | 8    | 12   |
+ ---- + ---- + --- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- +
```

Notice how all the group 3 records have data in the right table and the group 1 and 2 records have nulls there. Let's use this fact to perform the calculations. Modify the query:

```
select
          a1.ACCT
        , DATEPART(MM, a1.Mnth + ' 1 2017') as Mnth -- see what a pain it is to use strings instead of dates?
        , a1.Grp
        , a1.Val1
        , a1.Val2
        , (case a1.GRP when 1 then a1.Val1 + a1.Val2
                       when 2 then a1.Val1 - a1.Val2
                       when 3 then (case a2.Grp when 1 then a2.Val1 + a2.Val2
                                                when 2 then a2.Val1 - a2.Val2
                        end)
        end) as Calculation
    from ... -- same as above
```

This gives us our desired result:

```
+ ---- + ---- + --- + ---- + ---- + ----------- + 
| ACCT | Mnth | Grp | Val1 | Val2 | Calculation |
+ ---- + ---- + --- + ---- + ---- + ----------- + 
| A    | 1    | 1   | 2    | 5    | 7           | 
| A    | 2    | 2   | 4    | 9    | -5          |
| A    | 3    | 3   | 5    | 10   | -5          | 
| B    | 1    | 1   | 10   | 15   | 25          | 
| B    | 2    | 2   | 6    | 9    | -3          |  
| B    | 3    | 2   | 10   | 8    | 2           | 
| B    | 4    | 3   | 8    | 12   | 2           | 
| B    | 5    | 3   | 6    | 11   | 2           | 
+ ---- + ---- + --- + ---- + ---- + ----------- +
```

Note that we don't need the line `and a1.Grp = 3` because of the way we write our case statements. Remove that line and you'll see we get the same result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Really appreciate the effort and level of explanation. Regarding months, my actual data is not like this and is in fact datetime. I agree with your comments around that but was just using it for simplification in understanding. Anyways, thanks again! Very helpful and I'll try to apply it now.

Comment: @vdiddy Glad this helped, and happy to hear that you are using dates correctly :)